# Herencia en modelos de Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

En los modelos de `Django`, cuando se crea una clase que hereda de otra que no es abstracta, a efectos de base de datos, es como crear una relación **one-to-one** entre las dos tablas.

Partiendo del siguiente 
     ejemplo:

```
class A(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class A1(A):
    other_field = models.CharField(max_length=20)


object_a_1 = A1.objects.create(name="test1", other_field="test2")

object_a = A.objects.get(id=object_a_1.a_ptr_id)

print object_a_1.a_ptr == object_a
```

Mi pregunta es, ¿existe forma de crear la relación entre **A1** y **A** de manera inversa? es decir, 
    ¿partir del modelo A y crear posteriormente A1?

Pongo un ejemplo de lo que buscaría para conseguir el mismo resultado del ejemplo anterior.

¿Podría ser una opción válida? ¿Cuál podría ser la forma correcta?

```
object_a = A.objects.create(name="test1")

object_a_1 = A1.objects.create(a_ptr=object_a, other_field="test2")
```

En este caso, no funcionaría porque al crear `object_a_1` devuelve

> IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: modelos_a.timestamp

Comment: No hay ninguna relación en esas dos tablas a nivel de base de datos, para Django la tabla A y la tabla A1 son dos tablas distintas, la única diferencia es que la tabla A1 tiene un campo adicional además de los campos heredados desde A. Si quieres relaciones tienes que usar los campos que se crearon para ese propósito (`ForeignKey`, `OneToOneField`, `ManyToManyField`).

Comment: @Avara quizás te interese [¿Cómo etiquetamos las preguntas de Django?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3210/127)

Answer (score 1):

cuando usas herencias en model de django heredas los campos no el objeto. Me explico,  tú `class A1` ahora posee 3 `fields` el propio `(other_field)` + 2 de `A (timestamp, name)`, por lo que al momento de crear el objeto `A1` debes pasarle los 3 valores, bueno 2 ya que `timestamp es auto_add`

```
object_a_1 = A1.objects.create(other_field="test2", name="test2")
```

Si usas un objeto de otra clase para crear `A1` lo que intentas hacer es una relación.

Answer (score 0):

corriste migraciones? Django por defecto no recogería cambios en los modelos. Por otra parte, si no se especifica `null=True`, `blank=True`, se convierte en un campo obligatorio

Prueba esto

```
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null = True)
```

Comment: Existen las migraciones, y el campo A.timestamp tiene `auto_now_add=True` por lo que no tendría que haber problemas

Comment: Probaste añadiendo el `blank=true?`

Comment: @Dev.Joel Cómo podría quedar `blank` con `auto_now_add`?

Comment: En mi respuesta lo especifiqué , probar y me dices que tal fue

Comment: El error sigue siendo el mismo, ten en cuenta que el error que devuelve es `NOT NULL constraint failed`. Tampoco le veo el sentido ya que el objeto `object_a` ya existe en base de datos por lo que no debería dar ningún error